# How to manage tasks and contexts of working files like IntelliJ in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, task, productivity-power-tools

I want to switch between tasks like we do in Android Studio or IntelliJ by pressing Ctrl+Shift+T which shows the tasks or contexts we have added already. For example I would open 5 documents for a task A and 3 documents for task B. Now pressing Ctrl+Shift+T will show me a window to switch between A and B which will open the corresponding 5 or 3 windows.

[image]

Reference : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/11.0/switching-between-tasks.html